# Клик срабатывает со второго раза jquery

Tags: html, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('.mainmenubg').on('click',function(){
        $('.inp ').val($('#notification div.alert div a:first-child').text());
      });
    });
```

```html
<div class="block_incard">
  <div class="cart-btn incart-type1 mainmenubg ">
    <div class="incart-num">
      <input name="count" value="1" type="number">
      <span class="icons i_plus incart_up"></span>
      <span class="icons i_minus incart_down"></span>
    </div>
    <a href="/catalog/akkumulyatory/0-092-S30-000-akb-S3-40Ah-340A-175x175x190.html" title="В корзину" class="incart-js icons i_cart">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

что делаю не правильно?

Comment: а хтмл можете показать?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/c8opLrfh/
сразу срабатывает.

Comment: у вас ошибок в консоле нет?

Comment: нет только подгрузка шрифта

Comment: ну, смотрите, у вас `$(document).ready(function()`, может вы кликаете еще до того, как выполнилось это действие?.
попробуйте `$(document).ready(function(){ console.log("document ready");
$('.mainmenubg').on('click',function(){
console.log("click works");
    $('.inp ').val($('#notification div.alert div a:first-child').text());

});

 });` и после вывода уже кликайте

Comment: дело не в этом , сначала появляется document read потом кликаю, но результат такой же

Comment: окей... тогда где это нам искать  `$('.inp ').val($('#notification div.alert div a:first-child').text());`?

Comment: <div id="notification">
<div class="alert none" style="display: none;">
<a class="close" href="#"><i class="icons i_del3"></i></a>
<div>
<a href="/catalog/akkumulyatory/0-092-S40-100-akb-S4-80Ah-740A-315x175x175.html">АКБ S4 80Ah 740A 315x175x175 (-+)</a>
</div>
</div>

Comment: почему сразу не дать в впорос все данные?..
и еще раз, у меня все работает https://jsfiddle.net/c8opLrfh/1/

Comment: Пытаюсь сделать так $('.mainmenubg').on('click',function(){
        alert($('#notification div.alert div a:first-child').text());
  
    });
Смотри при первом клике выводится  пустое окно alert , а при втором клике уже выводит текст

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему, поставил setTimeout на клик а после этого уже выдергивал информацию

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.mainmenubg').on('click',function(){
  let text = $('#notification').children('div.alert').children('div').children('a').eq(1).text()
    $('.inp').val(text);
  });
});
```

Comment: что такое let ?

Comment: @gbrgbr это переменная нового стандарта